# python check existence of multiple multi level dict keys

Tags: python

How could this code be improved, or a method created, to checked for 1..N multi level dict key combinations?  I am unclear on a clean way to pass that information into a method if using that approach.

```
   try:
        foo = event['key1']['key2']['key3']
    except KeyError:
        try:
            foo = event['Key1']['Key2']
        except KeyError as e::
            print(f"Unable to get foo from event: {e}")
            foo = "unknown"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the perfect situation for a **recursive function**.

The following function takes as arguments a dictionary (`event`), an ordered list of `keys` and a counter variable `n` incremented at each recursion.

The function looks for the `n`-th element of `keys` in the `event` dictionary; if it finds the key, the respective value is assigned to the `event` variable, the counter is incremented and the function is called recursively with the new parameters.

If the key is not found, or the `n`-th element is out of `keys`' range, or if `event` is not a dict type anymore, the program stops and prints out the `event` variable itself, which is indeed the value of the key used in the previous recursion.

Also if the very first key is not found in the dictionary, an error is shown.

```
def find_key(event, keys, n=0):
    try:
        event = event[keys[n]]
        n += 1
        find_key(event, keys, n=n)
    except:
        print(event if n != 0 else "The first key you provided was not found in the dictionary.")
```

As you can see, the code's logic is pretty simple and straightforward, so for instance:

```
event = {"key1":{"key2":{"key3":{"key4": "Hello World!"}}}}
keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3", "key4"]

find_key(event, keys)
```

would print out:

```
>>>Hello World!
```

Comment: Very clean.  I did notice in testing that if you added "key5" to keys, it would not process correctly.  It returns "Hello World" when it should return an error.    Can you validate?

Answer (score 1):

You want to be able to specify some arbitrary-length path and move
through that path. If you're able to reach the end of the path, return
that value; otherwise, indicate the path cannot be reached.

```py
def probe(dictionary, path):
    first = True

    # Treat the empty path [] as a reference to .
    if not path:
        return dictionary

    for key in path:
        try:
            if first:
                value = dictionary[key]
                first = False
            else:
                value = value[key]
        # KeyError: dictionary has key accessor but not this
        # specific key.
        # TypeError: The object is either not subscriptable or
        # the key is not hashable.
        except (KeyError, TypeError):
            raise ValueError(f"The path {path} is not reachable in {dictionary}")

    return value
```

You can then call this like so:

```py
probe(some_dictionary, ["a", "b", "c"])
```

You could modify the signature like this (replacing references to `path` accordingly):

```
def probe(dictionary, *args):
```

and use a simpler syntax on calls:

```
probe(some_dictionary, "a", "b", "c")
```

Comment: I like this.  Wondering if we could also make "path" a list of lists so it could go in order and return first matching list of keys.

Comment: @tavor999 one basic approach to that problem would be to use this function inside a loop over your list of lists, and then break out of the loop on the first success. You might want to reduce the amount of effort up front (if two paths share a common parent path that you know is not accessible from an earlier attempt, you should not retry it).

Comment: I've used your answer as a base to build upon.  Checkout my answer.  Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

This is the perfect situation for a recursive function. The following solution assumes that the first item in the list passed will be found in the highest level of the nested dict, but that can be accounted for pretty easily if I had more time.

```
def check_key_combos(d, keys: list):
    if len(keys)==0:
        return d
    for key, val in d.items():
        if key == keys[0]:
            keys.pop(0)
            return check_key_combos(d[key],keys)
```

**Example:**
Dictionary 'd' is nested 4 layers with the final layer comprising of an array as a value.

```
>>>d
A
    1
        A
            1
                [8 9 8]
            2
                [7 8 5]
            3
                [6 3 9]
            4
                [3 3 4]
        B
            1
                [8 9 8]
            2
                [7 8 5]
            3
                [6 3 9]
            4
                [3 3 4]
        C
            1
                [8 9 8]
            2
                [7 8 5]
            3
                [6 3 9]
            4
                [3 3 4]
    2
        A
            1
                [8 9 8]
            2
                [7 8 5]
            3
                [6 3 9]
            4
                [3 3 4]
        B
            1
                [8 9 8]
            2
                [7 8 5]
            3
                [6 3 9]
            4
                [3 3 4]
        C
            1
                [8 9 8]
            2
                [7 8 5]
            3
                [6 3 9]
            4
                [3 3 4]
>>> nested_val = check_key_combos(d,['A','2','B','4'])
>>> nested_val
array([3, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

@crcvd had a very good answer but I had to modify it to suite my needs to maximize functionality in the method and reduce code on callers.  This does assume that keys are somewhat unique so last key, couldn't match an earlier position.

```
def probe(dictionary, list_of_lists, default):
    for path in list_of_lists:
        for key in path:
            try:
                value = value[key]
            except UnboundLocalError:
                # value needs to be instantiated
                value = dictionary[key]
            except (KeyError, TypeError):
                print(f"The path {path} at key {key} is not reachable in {dictionary}")
                break
            else:
                if path[-1] == key:
                    return value

    return default


target = {
    "k1": {
        "k2": {
            "k3": "k3 final value"
        }
    }
}

l1 = ["k1", "k2", "k3"]
l2 = ["k1", "k2", "k5"]

v = probe(target, [l1, l2], "default value")
print(f" value = {v}")
```